# Read Clickhouse using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, clickhouse

I want to read my clickhouse table using pyspark.read.format() but I am not able to do it,
However, I can write using Yandex driver but am unable to Read, I have also used clickhouse-driver for the same purpose but due to massive data it's crashing,
Please guide me in achieving the same, and thank you for your help.

Also, the clickhouse setup I am using doesn't have any password and is running on the default user so is that an issue?

```
spark.read.format('jdbc').option('driver','ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver').option('url','jdbc:clickhouse://hosturl:port').option('user','').option('password','').option('dbtable','table').load()
```

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. You need to provide some code so we can see what you have done so far and we will be able to help. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexB I have added a line which I am using to read the data please look into it